# iPhone SDK: Navigation is causing crash

Tags: iphone

My app is crashing when I navigate two view controllers in my application. For example, if I do this sequence:

RootController
ViewControllerA
ViewControllerB 
ViewControllerA

My app crashes.

It crashes when I pressed the back button in ViewControllerB. So, It seems like it is with two or more ViewControllers being pushed. Each by themselves work.

I don't know why.

```
This is the code I am using to invoke new views.

    salesViewController *anotherViewController = [[salesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"salesView" bundle:nil];
    //confirmViewController *anotherViewController = [[confirmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"confirmView" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES];
    [anotherViewController release];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more info. Console log maybe, or the context of which this code is being used. I'll say though it looks fishy that your class name starts with a lowercase "s"

Comment: @bpapa's right.  The console log will tell you more about what happened.

Comment: I am still having the problem. Weird thing is nothing goes to the console when the application crashes. I am not sure where to add debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news is that your code to create new views is just fine.  Bad news is that it's somewhere else.  I found [this conversation](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-462117.html) on the net that seems to be a similar issue.

Comment: Thank you for the URL. After I read the post, I realized my problem was that I was calling release after dealloc.